# Проверка загрузился ли iframe

Tags: jquery

Есть iframe виджет от facebook, нужно как то узнать загрузился ли он. Проблема в том что, он иногда загружается всего наполовину (подгружает скрипты, а html нет), он вроде загрузился и вроде нет.

Можно как то узнать загрузился ли html? Можно предлагать абсурдные идеи вроде соответствия первого пикселя по цвету и тд

Comment: Какой именно виджет?

Comment: это like box

Answer (score 1):

Вместо алерта — свою функцию.

```
<iframe onload="alert('Loaded!');" src="..."></iframe>
```

(ваш [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/jcSXy/6/))

Comment: Не работает. Хитрость в том что, фрейм фесбука загружается наполовину. 

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/jcSXy/7/

Зайдите на фидле авторизованным на фэйсбуке, и не авторизованным. Если вы авторизованны, то HTML загрузится. А если не авторизованны, то HTML загрузится на половину (до body).

Comment: А что вы хотите вообще в конце достичь? Ну узнали вы, показывает он фрейм или нет, а дальше что?

Comment: если не загрузится display:none

Comment: А вы знаете, почему он не подгружается?

Comment: потому что плагин требует авторизации на сайте facebook, как я понял он следит за пользователями.

Comment: И да, и нет — он требует авторизации только для того, чтобы проверить, что пользователь попадает в разрешенную группу. У своей страницы сделайте права доступа Everyone (13+) и (или) снимите ограничение по стране. Вот, например, лайкбокс страницы, у которых нет ограничений — он показывается даже не авторизованному на Facebook пользователю: http://jsfiddle.net/jcSXy/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ifr').ready /*т.е. полная загрузка тегов*/ {
   alert('ura!!!');
}
```